# Query SQL no meu Controller não executa no Servidor Erro 1142

Tags: sql, laravel, select

Eu criei um site com Laravel 5.7, e carreguei no servidor com os bancos de dados, tudo ok. Todas as *functions* do meu controller executam perfeitamente, menos a *function* abaixo:

```
public function consolidatedByMonth()
{
    $vistoriasAll = DB::select('SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(data),"-", YEAR(data)) as month, SUM(valor) as value FROM vistorias WHERE user_id="'.Auth::user()->id.'"GROUP BY MONTH(data);');
    $vistorias = collect($vistoriasAll)->reverse();

    return view('vistorias.listamensal')->with('vistorias', $vistorias);
}
```

Quando esta function é chamada pela View, ela retorna o seguinte erro:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'jcvis546_jcvisto'@'localhost' for table 'vistorias' (SQL: SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(data),"-", YEAR(data)) as month, SUM(valor) as value FROM jcvistoria.vistorias GROUP BY MONTH(data);)**

Alguém pode me ajudar qual a causa do erro, e como corrigir?

Comment: Seu GROUP BY não deveria ser: CONCAT(MONTH(data),"-", YEAR(data)) e não apenas por MONTH(data)?

Comment: Fiz como você sugeriu, e o erro ainda persiste, o mesmo erro. Estranho porque o usuário que estou usando tem todos os privilégios.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu não sei fazer isso ainda... você pode me instruir? Eu uso o cPanel do Hostgator

Comment: @Augusto Vasques meu provedor não dá acesso ao terminal... Você pode me explicar melhor o que você quis dizer com criar um app com privilégios de super usuário(root)? Você diz um app Laravel?

Comment: De uma lida [nisso aqui](https://suporte.hostgator.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/115000385293-Como-criar-um-novo-banco-de-dados-e-um-usu%C3%A1rio-atrav%C3%A9s-do-cPanel#passo%204) é do hostgator e fala sobre privilégios em BD. Se não resolver entra em contato com o suporte.